# Not able to test an event of Stencil app with Jest

Tags: jestjs, stenciljs

I'm trying to test a click event originated from an icon (`<i>`) in a Stencil component. The thing is I am able to debug the test and I see that the test triggers the correct method on the component, but Jest is not able to detect\register the event and the `toHaveBeenCalled()` method fails.

`input.spec.jsx`

```
  it("dispatches icon click event", async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [Input], //just the component name
      template: () => (<input-fields value="some input value"></input-fields>),
    });
  
    const eventSpy = jest.fn();
    page.win.addEventListener('input-field-search-event', eventSpy);

    await page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('.icon-container').click();
    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

`input.tsx`

```
  private dispatchSearchEvent(e){
    //i can stop ay this point with a break point and the data passed by the test is correct
    this.tipInputEnterEvent.emit({type: "input-field-search-event", event: e, data: this.value});
  }
```

the error

```
  ● Input tests › dispatches icon click event

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      334 |     await page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('.icon-container').click();
      335 |     await page.waitForChanges();
    > 336 |     expect(eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
          |                      ^
      337 |   });
      338 |
      339 | });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the name of custom events is the property name, in your case `tipInputEnterEvent`. So the listener should instead be:

```js
page.win.addEventListener('tipInputEnterEvent', eventSpy);
```

You can also change the event name if you want:

```
@Event({ eventName: 'input-field-search-event' }) tipInputEnterEvent: EventEmitter;
```